# Hosting DSML SOAP Endpoint

Tags: ldap, opends, dsml

I have an OpenDS directory service (LDAP) and OpenDS' DSML Gateway installed.  I'm able to successfully connect to my DSML gateway via JXplorer (so I know it's up).  Now what I'd like to do is be able to host that gateway as a SOAP endpoint w/ WSDL so I can hit it via SoapUI.  Am I missing an easy way to make that happen or do I need to code my own service to deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DSML Gateway actually hosts under 8080.  It was a matter of getting the header right and it was a SOAP call away.  No coding needed.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want/need a WSDL file for the DSML Gateway, you can find one here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2348967/dsmlQueryService.wsdl
Make sure you change the end point at the end of the document to point to the running DSML service.
Enjoy.